# Отправка запроса к api vkontakte

Tags: ajax, вконтакте

Здравствуйте! 
У меня появилась проблема по api vkontakte, дело в том что мне надо отправить определенный запрос vk api и притом это надо сделать без перезагрузки страницы, то есть аяксом, но целях безопасности браузеры блокируют такой запрос, подскажите как мне отправить запрос к api без перезагрузки страницы..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему блокируют? Отправляйте через CURL - а отправить и получить ответ через ajax. У меня всё прекрасно работает.

Comment: А могли бы Вы скинуть какой нибудь исходник???

Comment: Лучше скиньте вы, я посмотрю - если что, что исправлю.
vitalik.tjuryakin@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Всё просто. Если хотите использовать именно ajax, то используйте протокол передачи jsonp.
Т.е. в ajax запросе будет:
`dataType: 'jsonp'`
и callback функция.

JSONP (JSON Padding) или «JSON с подкладкой» является расширением JSON, когда имя функции обратного вызова указывается в качестве входного аргумента.
К примеру:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/getjson?jsonp=parseResponse"></script>`

Здесь параметр jsonp содержит имя callback функции parseResponse.
Посторонний сервер example.com может вернуть следующий код:

`parseResponse({"paper": "A4", "count": 5})`

Теперь код вызывает javascript-функцию первого домена.